# Excel: Insert multiple rows based on specific values to the last row

Tags: excel, vba

This question may already answered by the other posts.
Here's my problem

Sheet1 : The picture illustrates the data table that I made. It consists 3 fields with 3 rows and 1 blank row.

[image]

[image]

The button insert contains the code below

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim Answer As Integer
Dim NumLines As Integer
Dim count As Integer

Answer = InputBox("How many lines to insert? (50 lines maximum)")
NumLines = Int(Val(Answer))
If NumLines > 50 Then
   NumLines = 50
End If
'End sub exectuion if no lines to insert
If NumLines = 0 Then
    GoTo EndInsertLines
End If
'Insert specified number of lines at the cursor
Do
    Selection.EntireRow.Insert
    count = count + 1
Loop While count < NumLines
EndInsertLines:

End Sub
```

The above code will perform the insert rows based on the inputted values when the inputbox prompts to the user.

What I'm aiming to do is,

When I try to put my preferred value it will automatically add up to the last row of data.

For example:
The number of rows that I want to add is 3.
It will automatically adds up 3 rows below of the last data registered on the table. As illustrated in the picture the last data is *Data3 located at column X* it should add up below of that data.

Comment: When you type in the row below a table Excel will automatically expand the table to include that row, passing all the formats and even formulas into the new row. So, what does your button do that Excel doesn't do automatically?

Comment: Sorry just a newbie in excel and VBA.

Is that possible to append new row by just typing to the table ?

Comment: What happens if the selection is outside your table?

Comment: yes, if you type in the row immediately below a table but within the columns covered by the table, the row will be added to the table automatically. If you copy data from elsewhere and paste into the row below the table, all the pasted rows will be added.

Comment: As of now nothing. But I'm planning to lock the other cells outside the table so that only the table can be modified. If it is possible. Still working on it

Comment: Is there any settings that I need to set? because my table isn't like that

Comment: Could you rezize the table by the number of rows from `InputBox`?  Also, why the 50 row limit?

Comment: Just a validation for 50

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below assumes you only have 1 table in your worksheet. This will add new rows at the bottom of the table. But like it was mentioned in the comment section that the table should expand automatically by default.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim myTable As Object
Set myTable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)
Dim numLines As Integer
numLines = InputBox("How many lines..?")

For i = 1 To numLines
 myTable.ListRows.Add alwaysinsert:=True

Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: Woaah! This one saved me!